# How to determine high and low threshold value of two matrixes from mean and standard deviation

Tags: matlab, math, image-processing, probability, probability-density

I have two matrixesthat belongs gaussian distribtion.The size are 3x3. Now, I want to estimate up and down threshold of their matrixes. I denote mean and standard deviation of each matrix is μ1;μ2 and σ1;σ2. The high and low threshold are

```
T_hight=(μ1+μ2)./2+k1∗(σ1+σ2)./2

T_low=(μ1+μ2)./2-k2∗(σ1+σ2)./2
```

where k1,k2 is const

My question is "Is my formula correct? Because this is gaussian distribution, so k1=k2,Right? And this is my code. Could you check have me"

```
μ1=mean(v1(:));first matrix 
σ1=std2(v1(:));
μ2=mean(v2(:));second matrix 
σ2=std2(v2(:));
k1=k2=1; 
T_hight=(μ1+μ2)./2+k1∗(σ1+σ2)./2;
T_low=(μ1+μ2)./2-k2∗(σ1+σ2)./2;
```

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you are doing.  What is k1, k2 and what do you mean by "up and down threshold"? Are you adding the matrices? If so have a look at [Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables) the resulting sd should be `sqrt(σ1^2+σ2^2)`.

Comment: k1 and k2 is const. They are weight factor. T_high and T_low are low and high threshold that I need. I not sure my formula is correct or not? That is first question. And your reference is only sum of two normal distributions. My distribution is mean of two normal distribtions. I think they are difference

Comment: The mean will just be half the sum so it is `(μ1+μ2)./2 +/- k1∗(sqrt(σ1^2+σ2^2))./2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the formula you are using, the joint standard deviation is wrong.it should be

```
T_high=(μ1+μ2)./2+k1∗sqrt((σ1^2+σ2^2)/2);
T_low=(μ1+μ2)./2-k2∗sqrt((σ1^2+σ2^2)/2);
```

As you treat all 18 pixels as belonging to the same distribution, why not use the following

```
v=[v1(:);v2(:)];
μ=mean(v); 
σ=std(v);
k1=k2=1; 
T_high=μ+k1*σ;
T_low=μ-k2∗σ1;
```

Comment: Thank you. I am wrong when use std2. Your way is good but how about if my maxtrix is large dimension. Can it work?

Comment: std2 is meant for 2-d matrices, for vector it is the same as std. So it is Ok to write std2(v1(:)), but it is more idiomatic to write std(v1(:)) or std2(v1)

Comment: If your data is a big matrix of logical, 8-bit integer of 16-bit integer, you may benefit in speed from using std2. Otherwise, std2 just calls std.